# How can I get the visibilty transition to delay?

Tags: javascript, css, delay, transition, visibility

The following snippet is pretty much a verbatim copy of my project so far (I've swapped out font-awesome stuff for question marks and the images are different).

I'm trying to fade the nav bar in and out with scroll and in order to prevent "invisible" menu items being clickable, I need to set `visibilty: hidden;` to them.

The transition is working great on scroll-up, but on scroll-down, the visibility transition happens immediately even though I've added a delay to it in CSS. I can't for the life of me figure the problem. Am I missing something?

```js
var minHeaderHeight = 100; // Height of shrunken header, in pixels
var header = document.querySelector("#header"); // The header object
var maxHeaderHeight = outerHeight(header, true); // Height of expanded header, in pixels

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initHeader);

function initHeader() {
 var landingImage = document.getElementById("landing-image");
 if (landingImage !== null) { 
  header.classList.add("expanded");
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCallback);
 } else {
  header.parentNode.style.paddingTop = minHeaderHeight + "px";
 }
}

function scrollCallback() {
 var scrollOffset = windowScrollTop();
 var transitionEvent;
 if (scrollOffset > 10) {
  header.classList.remove("expanding");
  header.classList.add("shrinking");
  header.classList.remove("expanded");
 } else {
  header.classList.remove("shrinking");
  header.classList.add("expanding");
  header.classList.add("expanded");
 }
}

// THESE TWO FUNCTIONS REPLICATE SIMILAR FUNCTIONS FROM JQUERY
function outerHeight(el, withMargins) {
 withMargins = withMargins || false;
 if (withMargins) {
   var height = el.offsetHeight;
   var style = getComputedStyle(el);
   height += parseInt(style.marginTop) + parseInt(style.marginBottom);
   return height;
 } else {
  return el.offsetHeight;
 }
}

function windowScrollTop(pos) {
 if (typeof pos === 'undefined') {
  if (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) {
   return window.pageYOffset;
  } else {
   return (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  }
 } else {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = pos;
  document.body.parentNode.scrollTop = pos;
  document.body.scrollTop = pos;
  window.pageYOffset = pos;
 }
}
```

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}

#header a {
 color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header-inner {
 width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
 
#header.expanded {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: transparent;
}

#header.expanding {
 -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -o-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
}

#header.shrinking {
 -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -o-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
}

#header-logos {
 position: relative;
}

#header-logos img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 max-height: 100px;
}

#header.shrinking img {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#header.expanding img {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.header-button {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
  -ms-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
}

#header.expanded .header-button {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
  -ms-transition: visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
  -o-transition: visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
  transition: visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
}

#header-logo-top {
 opacity: 0;
}

#header.expanded #header-logo-top {
 opacity: 1;
}

#header.expanded img {
  max-height: 500px;
}

#landing-image {
 height: 100vh;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

#landing-image.home-page {
 background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/KANTHALLOOR%2CEruvikulam%26Anamalais_in_the_background.jpg");
}

#page-content {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-inner">
   <div class="header-button menu-bars">
       <a href="#">?</a>
   </div>
    <div id="header-link-1" class="header-button">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="header-link-2" class="header-button">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id ="header-logos">
   <a href="#"><img id="header-logo-bottom" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/1000px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png"></a>
   <a href="#"><img id="header-logo-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e2/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.svg/2000px-Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.svg.png"></a>
   </div>
    <div id="header-dates" class="header-button">
        1 | 2 | 3 JAN 2018
    </div>
    <div id="header-socials" class="header-button">
   <a href="#">?</a>
   <span>|</span>
   <a href="#">?</a>
   <span>|</span>
   <a href="#">?</a>
   <span>|</span>
   <a href="#">?</a>
   <span>|</span>
   <a href="#">?</a>
    </div>
   <div class="header-button spacer">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="landing-image" class="home-page"></div> 
<div id="page-content">
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque magna non dui auctor placerat. Vestibulum cursus placerat mauris eget luctus. Maecenas sollicitudin mauris id erat porttitor, in dapibus ligula commodo. Donec sagittis sagittis felis non elementum. Nam facilisis non sapien non ultrices. Morbi cursus molestie nibh non tincidunt. Sed sagittis erat eu enim condimentum, ut lobortis nisi faucibus. Cras orci felis, molestie in ligula sit amet, vestibulum malesuada augue. Nullam id aliquam enim, eu vestibulum massa. Mauris ultricies ante sit amet leo ullamcorper, a lacinia nulla hendrerit. Aenean eros dolor, semper non nisi eu, maximus accumsan felis. Donec facilisis pellentesque lacus, quis vestibulum ipsum pretium tempus.
</div>
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the nav bar seems to fade in and out at the same speed (using IE11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not visibility transition happening immediately but rather opacity becoming `0` instantly.

In your example `#header.expanded .header-button` has `transition: visibility 0ms linear 300ms;` which disables opacity transition declared for `.header-button`.

Adding opacity transition explicitly for `#header.expanded .header-button` should do the trick.

```js
var minHeaderHeight = 100; // Height of shrunken header, in pixels
var header = document.querySelector("#header"); // The header object
var maxHeaderHeight = outerHeight(header, true); // Height of expanded header, in pixels

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initHeader);

function initHeader() {
 var landingImage = document.getElementById("landing-image");
 if (landingImage !== null) { 
  header.classList.add("expanded");
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCallback);
 } else {
  header.parentNode.style.paddingTop = minHeaderHeight + "px";
 }
}

function scrollCallback() {
 var scrollOffset = windowScrollTop();
 var transitionEvent;
 if (scrollOffset > 10) {
  header.classList.remove("expanding");
  header.classList.add("shrinking");
  header.classList.remove("expanded");
 } else {
  header.classList.remove("shrinking");
  header.classList.add("expanding");
  header.classList.add("expanded");
 }
}

// THESE TWO FUNCTIONS REPLICATE SIMILAR FUNCTIONS FROM JQUERY
function outerHeight(el, withMargins) {
 withMargins = withMargins || false;
 if (withMargins) {
   var height = el.offsetHeight;
   var style = getComputedStyle(el);
   height += parseInt(style.marginTop) + parseInt(style.marginBottom);
   return height;
 } else {
  return el.offsetHeight;
 }
}

function windowScrollTop(pos) {
 if (typeof pos === 'undefined') {
  if (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) {
   return window.pageYOffset;
  } else {
   return (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  }
 } else {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = pos;
  document.body.parentNode.scrollTop = pos;
  document.body.scrollTop = pos;
  window.pageYOffset = pos;
 }
}
```

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}

#header a {
 color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header-inner {
 width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
 
#header.expanded {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: transparent;
}

#header.expanding {
 -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -o-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
}

#header.shrinking {
 -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
 -o-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, background 300ms ease-in;
}

#header-logos {
 position: relative;
}

#header-logos img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 max-height: 100px;
}

#header.shrinking img {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#header.expanding img {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.header-button {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
  -ms-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
}

#header.expanded .header-button {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
  -ms-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, visibility 0ms linear 300ms;
}

#header-logo-top {
 opacity: 0;
}

#header.expanded #header-logo-top {
 opacity: 1;
}

#header.expanded img {
  max-height: 500px;
}

#landing-image {
 height: 100vh;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

#landing-image.home-page {
 background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/KANTHALLOOR%2CEruvikulam%26Anamalais_in_the_background.jpg");
}

#page-content {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-inner">
   <div class="header-button menu-bars">
       <a href="#">?</a>
   </div>
    <div id="header-link-1" class="header-button">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="header-link-2" class="header-button">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id ="header-logos">
   <a href="#"><img id="header-logo-bottom" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/1000px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png"></a>
   <a href="#"><img id="header-logo-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e2/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.svg/2000px-Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.svg.png"></a>
   </div>
    <div id="header-dates" class="header-button">
        1 | 2 | 3 JAN 2018
    </div>
    <div id="header-socials" class="header-button">
   <a href="#">?</a>
   <span>|</span>
   <a href="#">?</a>
   <span>|</span>
   <a href="#">?</a>
   <span>|</span>
   <a href="#">?</a>
   <span>|</span>
   <a href="#">?</a>
    </div>
   <div class="header-button spacer">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="landing-image" class="home-page"></div> 
<div id="page-content">
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque magna non dui auctor placerat. Vestibulum cursus placerat mauris eget luctus. Maecenas sollicitudin mauris id erat porttitor, in dapibus ligula commodo. Donec sagittis sagittis felis non elementum. Nam facilisis non sapien non ultrices. Morbi cursus molestie nibh non tincidunt. Sed sagittis erat eu enim condimentum, ut lobortis nisi faucibus. Cras orci felis, molestie in ligula sit amet, vestibulum malesuada augue. Nullam id aliquam enim, eu vestibulum massa. Mauris ultricies ante sit amet leo ullamcorper, a lacinia nulla hendrerit. Aenean eros dolor, semper non nisi eu, maximus accumsan felis. Donec facilisis pellentesque lacus, quis vestibulum ipsum pretium tempus.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Mac. This did get me on the right track but I forgot to update this thread.